# Чтение опр.колво байтов из файла

Tags: c#

Всем добрый вечер.
Возник вот такой вопрос:
Допустим у меня есть файл,я хочу считать с него 128 байт и перевести их в `string` с помощью класса `Encoding`. Но при этом у меня в этих 128 байтов занято только 32. 
Строковая переменная после использования класса `Encoding`, может выглядеть примерно так: `firstdsda` (Допустим это 32 байт), а дальше все выглядит в таком виде `0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0` (это допустим те 96 оставшиеся,то есть пустые байты).

Если выводить эту переменную с помощью `Messagebox.show(Это строка);` то текст в начале, а дальше идут пустые байты но их не видно.

Так вот как можно при выводе\показе\ и так далее отрезать оставшееся пустые байты?

Comment: string.TrimEnd?

Comment: Firstfffff\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0 Вот к примеру такая переменная.Как от нее все пустые байты отрезать?А так спасибо вроде бы метод то что надо.Но что то не вышло.

Comment: Проблема решена.Использовал такое char[] array = {'\0'};Спасибо.

Comment: Оформлю тогда как ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте

```
s.TrimEnd('\0');
```

(`s` — ваша строка, полученная из `Encoding.GetString`).

Это мне кажется лучше, чем убирать финальные нули из массива байт, т. к. они могут быть важны в вашей кодировке.

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо знать кодировку, в которой записана строка, поэтому Encoding.UTF8 может варьироваться:

```
var bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("имя_файла");
var str = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes, 0, 128);
```

Так же есть альтернатива для больших файлов:

```
using (var stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead("имя_файла"))
{
     var buffer = new byte[128];
     stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
     var str = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо но думаю способ выше более подходит.К тому же он легче.